# Is there any way to create emulator for Linux KVM

Tags: linux, emulation, kvm

I want to test Linux KVM functionality. So to test, Instead of creating the Linux KVM (Hypervisor), I want to setup the emulator for that, which reduces the cost of hardware/resources.

Please let me know if is there any way to create emulator for Linux KVM ?

Comment: Are you just looking for the instructions? http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/HOWTO

Comment: A hypervisor is a way to avoid emulation. I would guess that [qemu](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page) can emulate enough hardware to start a (slow) hypervisor. I think also [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/VirtualBox) (which is more of a hypervisor itself) could too.

Answer (score 0):

As you are looking for the emulation then [BOCHS](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/) is your choice. One of the `KVM`'s requirements is the `Virtualization` support by the host `CPU`.

According to the [chip support list](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/doc/docbook/user/cpu-models.html) it emulates `AMD Phenom X3 8650` among other AMD and Intel models. The real `AMD Phenom X3 8650` does support `AMD-V` technology. However, I can't tell you to what extent the implementation is complete. Anyway, you could try all emulated `AMD` models that supports `AMD-V` and `Intel` models that supports `VT-x` and see what happens.

However, do not expect it to be sufficiently fast as you are going to run `KVM` guest inside `KVM` host running inside `BOCHS` emulator.

Comment: Thanks all for your help. Modifying question like, I am looking to simulate the libvirt library. So, that simulation doesn't required actual hardware resources.

Comment: @Arun TBH I do not see the point of your study. Anyway, good luck.